# Can You Set a Nested Environment Variable in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod running dotnet that leverages an [appsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#appsettingsjson) file. I have the following entry for RabbitMq:

appsettings.json

```
{
  ...
  "RabbitMQ": {
    "HostName": "localhost",
    "UserName": "someuser",
    "Password": "somepassword"
  }
}
```

I am trying to update the **RabbitMQ.HostName** property within my deployment yaml like so:

```
env:
  - name: "RabbitMQ:HostName"
    value: "rabbitmq-cluster-deployment.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local"
```

It doesn't work. I have tried different variations but nothing looks like it sets it.

Does Kubernetes have a way of setting the "nested property" or no? I am aware that the `:` character is not allowed. I have tried using `.` which didn't throw an error, but also didn't work. The reason I was thinking it was a `:` is because that is how you would do it with dotnet.

Example: `_configuration["RabbitMQ:HostName"]`

Other "non-nested" environment variables are set just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the `name` field and replace `:` with double underscores `__`

Instead of

```
env:
  - name: "RabbitMQ:HostName"
    value: "rabbitmq-cluster-deployment.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local"
```

use

```
env:
  - name: RabbitMQ__HostName
    value: "rabbitmq-cluster-deployment.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local"
```